# Discord Bot has problems with Tenor API

Tags: python, discord, bots

So i have setup everything with the Discord Bot and the Tenor api and it worked until a day ago and i cant seem to figure out the Problem.
I Tried Reinstalling the ext for Discord and python but it wont work.
I know it isnt the Prettiest code but i want to work on that later when the bot is almost done

Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.venvs/discord/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/root/.venvs/discord/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/root/.venvs/discord/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'results'
```

and now the 2 codes one from Tenor and the other one from me

Tenor API

```
def get_gif(searchTerm):  # PEP8: lower_case_names for functions
    response = requests.get("https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q={}&key={}&limit=1".format(searchTerm, TenorToken))
    data = response.json()
    

         
    return data['results'][0]['media'][0]['gif']['url']
```

call for the API from me

```
@bot.command(name='umarmen', description="umarmen")
async def umarmen(ctx, *, member):
        
        #print(member1)
        n = random.randint(0,5)

        if n == 1:
            gif_url = get_gif("Anime Hug") 
        elif n == 2:
            gif_url = get_gif("Anime Hug yuri-yuri") 
        elif n == 3:
            gif_url = get_gif("Anime Hugs sweet") 
        elif n == 4:
            gif_url = get_gif("Anime Hugs") 
        elif n == 5:
            gif_url = get_gif("Anime Hug zero-two") 
        elif n == 0:
            gif_url = get_gif("Anime Hug Love") 




        embed = discord.Embed(description=f'{ctx.message.author.display_name} Umarmt dich {member}')
        embed.set_image(url=gif_url)
    
        #await ctx.send (f'{ctx.message.author.display_name} Umarmt dich {member}')
        #print({member})
        await ctx.message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Did you tried using a debugger or just `print(data)` ?

Comment: yes but in the debugger there was no problem just with a import that i havent ahd on my pc